# How to mount writable samba shares?

Tags: samba, mac, cifs

I'd like to mount a folder from my Mac on my Ubuntu machine. So far I've enabled file sharing on my Mac and enabled Samba.

On Ubuntu I am able to connect to the share by simply navigating to `smb://servername` and I can see all my files. Great!

So I installed `cifs-utils` so that I had the cifs files available, then I created an empty folder `/mnt/david_mac`, and then manually mounted the share using,
 `sudo mount -t cifs //serverName/david -o 'username=myUsername,password=myPassword,rw,nounix,noserverinfo,sec=ntlmssp' /mnt/david_mac`

I can then see my files and folders fine in the `/mnt` folder. However I cannot write to them. What piece of the puzzle am I missing in order to be able to write files back to the Mac from my Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all things, I found the solution to this issue right after posting this question. The solution is in, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631510/samba-cannot-write-issue

The primary thing being that you need to pass `file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777` as part of your options in `mount`